# Oracle SQL: FROM keyword not found where expected

Tags: sql, oracle

Can anyone help with the following SQL please.  I'm getting and error from Oracle SQL Developer "ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected", which usually is just because of a missing or misplaced comma.  I just cannot see it in this one.

```
with counts AS (
select country_cd, count(*) as cnt
from country_use_def
group by country_cd)
select *, RANK() OVER(ORDER BY cnt DESC) as rank
from counts;
```

The error is pointing at the 'select *,' on line 5.  If I remove the , and the RANK and OVER clauses it works but the I would like to keep the RANK/OVER in the query.

Comment: You need to change your alias: "*rank*" is a reserved keyword.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not in the window function itself, but in the alias you're using for the window function. Since "*rank*" is a [reserved keyword](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/appdev.920/a42525/apb.htm), the DBMS will be attempting to treat your alias as if it were a window function.

Rename your alias to, say "rn", and the DBMS won't complain about it.

```
WITH counts AS (
    SELECT country_cd, 
           COUNT(*) as cnt
    FROM country_use_def
    GROUP BY country_cd
)
SELECT *, 
       RANK() OVER(ORDER BY cnt DESC) AS rn
FROM counts;
```